# How do I use Generics to create multiple/nested SelectMany joins in Linq for DocumentDB

Tags: c#, linq, azure, generics, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to add a method to a Generic Repository for Document Db.

I would like it produce SQL that looks similar to this (but generic):

```
SELECT VALUE c FROM c
JOIN versions IN c["versions"] 
JOIN groups IN versions["userGroups"] 
JOIN users IN groups["users"] 
WHERE c.type = "Approval" and users["userId"] = "xxx"
```

I have tried this...

```
public async Task<ListResult<TResult>> SelectManyAsync<TEntity1, TEntity2, TEntity3, TEntity4, TResult>(Expression<Func<TEntity1, bool>> condition01, Expression<Func<TEntity1, IEnumerable<TEntity2>>> condition02, Expression<Func<TEntity2, IEnumerable<TEntity3>>> condition03, Expression<Func<TEntity3, IEnumerable<TEntity4>>> condition04, Expression<Func<TEntity4, bool>> condition05) where TEntity1:class
        {
            var feedOptions = GetFeedOptions();

            var query = DocumentDbContext.Client.CreateDocumentQuery<TEntity1>(DocumentDbContext.DocumentCollection.DocumentsLink, feedOptions)
                .Where(condition01)
                .SelectMany(condition02)
                .SelectMany(condition03)
                .SelectMany(condition04)
                .Where(condition05)
                .AsDocumentQuery();

// .. removed code for brevity

}
```

which results in something like this:

```
SELECT VALUE tmp FROM root 
JOIN tmp IN root["versions"] 
JOIN tmp IN tmp["userGroups"] 
WHERE (true AND (tmp["userId"] = "xxx"))
```

but I get the error:

> The input set name or alias 'tmp' is specified more than once in the
>   FROM clause.

Is it possible to create something like this using generics and how could we specify different values for "tmp". or is this not the correct approach?

Comment: how is your condition expressions looks like ? is it auto generated?

Comment: No, this is coded where required. this example compiles but has the runtime error: approvals = await _approvals.SelectManyAsync<Approval, ApprovalVersion, ApprovalGroup, ApprovalUser, Approval>(ownerQuery, approval => approval.Versions, version => version.ApprovalGroups, approvalGroups => approvalGroups.Users, approvalUserQuery);

Comment: The main issue is trying to build up a query using a predicateBuilder and multiple SelectMany's to pass to a generic method that will get a filtered, ordered, adapted list.

Comment: I have a workaround to using a dynamically created sql statement with parameters, but would prefer using Linq for a more generic solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this bug or not, bug such query wont work. You need to use nested selectMany.

Following example should work:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<TRes>> Query<T, TRes>(
        string docCollection,
        string partitionKey,
        Func<IOrderedQueryable<T>, IQueryable<TRes>> func,
        string continuationToken = null)
    {
        var queryable =
            CosmosClient.CreateDocumentQuery<T>(
                CollectionUri(docCollection),
                new FeedOptions
                {
                    MaxItemCount = 100,
                    RequestContinuation = continuationToken,
                    EnableCrossPartitionQuery = false,
                    PartitionKey = new PartitionKey(partitionKey),
                    PopulateQueryMetrics = true,
                });

        return await func(queryable).AsDocumentQuery().ExecuteNextAsync<TRes>();
    }


await Query<Doc, string>("collection", "pk",
            (IOrderedQueryable<Doc> x) => x.SelectMany(p => p.Versions.SelectMany(d => d.UserGroups.SelectMany(k => k.Users.Select(u => u.Name)))));
```